# получить точки полигона

Tags: sql, postgresql

Использую PostgreSQL, версия 9.4. Есть полигон, например:

```
select '((0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1))'::polygon
```

Любой в общем. Как средствами БД извлечь набор точек, которые составляют этот полигон?
Ожидаемый результат:

```
(0,0)
(1,0)
(1,1)
(0,1)
```

Comment: используете postgis ?

Comment: Нет, postgis не использую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил вопрос созданием следующей функции:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_polygon_points(_polygon polygon) RETURNS SETOF point AS
$BODY$DECLARE
  rec_ RECORD;
  p_   POINT;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_ IN EXECUTE 'SELECT regexp_matches(''' || _polygon::TEXT || ''', ''' || E'\\([\\d\\.|-]+,[\\d\\.|-]+\\)' || ''', ''g'') AS pts' LOOP
    SELECT INTO p_ (array_to_string(rec_.pts, '##'))::point;
    RETURN NEXT p_;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

Работает следующим образом:

- функция преобразует полигон в текст;
- выделяет из получившегося текста по regexp'у все подстроки вида `(\d+,\d+)`;
- преобразует каждую такую подстроку в тип `point` и возвращает очередное значение.

Comment: Может у кого-то есть что добавить к этому решению?

Comment: Без PostGIS и добавлять-то нечего, только подобными костылями и выкручиваться. Хотя, я бы, пожалуй, делал через преобразование строки в массив. Но сути дела не меняет, все те же костыльные выдергивания точек из строки, может, чуточку по производительнее.